# Function which concatenates 2 strings (k and k-1 times)

Tags: python, string, function, concatenation, repeat

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to create a function that allows concatenating `x` and `y` where `x` appears `k` times and `y` appears `k-1`.

The output should be: `x` for `n = 1`,`xy` for `n = 2`, `xyx` for `n = 3`, `xyxy` for `n = 4`.

After many tries, I couldn’t find the solution.

```py
def assem(k: int):
    k > 0
    return ''.join('x' and 'y' for i in range(k))


print(assem(5))
```

Thank you.

Comment: What did you try? Please, spend some time reading ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you for editing my question and for the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
''.join('x' if i%2==0 else 'y' for i in range(n))
# n=3
# xyx
# n=4
# xyxy
```

Comment: Thank you ! I didn't use the right code when I've tried to use join. Is there another way (without using 'for') to obtain the same result ? Thanks.

Comment: @Sarah what do you mean? explain your wrong

Comment: I didn't put the condition if i % 2 == 0.

Comment: @Sarah now do you have a problem or not?

Comment: @Sarah if this correct please read this link : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: I have another question (sorry). If we want to insert 'y' between two 'x' to obtain :
'x' when k = 1, 'xyx' when k = 2 , ...etc. How should we change the code ? Thank you ! (I read a lot on different forums but I couldn't obtain the good result).

Comment: @Sarah welcome, is this what you want : `''.join('x' if i==0 else 'yx' for i in range(3))`??

Comment: Not sure. I mean, we can't obtain xy when k = 2, because we should have xyx , which means k-1 for y (sorry for the quality of my english).

Comment: @Sarah welcome girl. please give me some example for different n. like when n=2 what is output and when n=3 what is output and ....

Comment: Ok. This is what I did (I changed a little bit your code)

def assem (k: int):

    k > 0
    return 'y'.join('x' if k % 2 == 0 else 'y' for k in range(k)) 

output : 

for k = 0,  nothing
for k = 1,  x
for k = 2,  xyx
for k = 3, xyxyx
-------
I tried to find another way to, instead of calling a for function, I could only insert y between two x, by respecting the k (number of x) and the k-1 (number of y) condition. 
Reason : I have to simplify to reduce the cyclomatic number and the Halstead volume of the code. 
Thank you so much !

Comment: I'm thinking about a split function. I will try it to see if it works.

Comment: @Sarah excuse me for the delay, I will check your comment

Comment: no, no problem, take your time please, and thanks again.

Comment: @Sarah check this link for running code: https://onecompiler.com/python/3xagkez5b, is this your answer?

Comment: Thank you. In fact, that's what I'm trying to change by avoiding if, and finding a way to use for example : index, and multiplication ([:]. (I don't know if I can ask you again because I'm using your time and sorry for that).

Comment: @Sarah, yes Certainly, change the code on this link then I get your opinion : https://onecompiler.com/python/3xagkez5b

Comment: Please, check the link : https://onecompiler.com/python/3xagny3wx
(no if condition). Thanks

Comment: @Sarah, I check your link. you want to change this to `x` and `y`?

Comment: It's the final version (after changing a small part of your code). Sorry, this is the good one  with x and y : https://onecompiler.com/python/3xagny3wx .  Now it worked, and I could eliminate the Halstead volume problem and the cyclomatic complex problem. I don't know how to thank you. Mille mercis !

Comment: @Sarah welcome dude. You did it all yourself :))